# Configure C++ ClangFormat in Visual Studio 2022 to Use Tabs Instead of Spaces

Tags: visual-studio, clang-format

I have Visual Studio 2022 configured to use LLVM ClangFormat with "Keep tabs". When I am editing and press the tab key, the editor correctly inserts a tab. But when I paste items or format my document using `ctrl-k + d`, it inserts spaces instead.

The Options window suggests disabling Text Editor > Advanced > Adaptive formatting, but this seems to make no difference on this behaviour.

How do I configure Visual Studio 2022 to use tabs when formatting with LLVM ClangFormat?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify LLVM ClangFormat to use tabs by creating a `.clang-format` file in the same directory as your `.vcxproj` file with the `UseTab: Always` and `BasedOnStyle: LLVM` settings. For example:

```
---
BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Always
```